# Check all check box and send all updated status as a Object [Angular Js]

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have used this

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <form>
        <input type="checkbox" onclick="for(c in document.getElementsByName('rfile')) document.getElementsByName('rfile').item(c).checked = this.checked" >Check All </button>

            <table>
            <thead>
                <tr role="row">
                        <th>Student ID</th>
                        <th>Status</th>     
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="result in searchResults">
                <td ><a href="#/Attendance/edit/{{result.id}}">{{result.studentId}}</a>
                </td>
                <td ><input type="checkbox" name="rfile" ng-model="result.status" /> {{result.status}}</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
                </table>
                <div>
                <button ng-click="save()">Save</button>

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </form>
</div>
```

It is perfectly checking all the checkbox but it is not updating the status.

what should i do.. When i click individual checkbox for updating it works perfectly.

TIA
I m beginner ..so please dont give down vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use ng-click or ng-change to manipulate your scope data and put all result status to true (or false).

Here a plunker to illustrate it : 
https://plnkr.co/edit/YW6opuPTgtXXg08OzbM6?p=preview

See your checkbox to check all

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-click="onCheckAll()" ng-model="checkAll">Check All
```

Comment: Yes . Its perfect.   `  $scope.onCheckAll = function() {
    angular.forEach($scope.searchResults, function(r) {
      r.status = $scope.checkAll;
    })`             can you explain this for me? I don't understand specially `r.status=$scope.checkAll` this line.

Comment: I defined an ng-model on the input to variable checkAll. That's means angularjs put on $scope.checkAll the value of the checkbox.
After I defined the function onCheckAll and I bind it on ng-click of checkbox. So when we click on checkbox, angular call my function.

In this function I loop on searchResults collection and for each result I set the status to the value of the checkbox (with my var $scope.checkAll).
Angularjs manage HTML to check all checkbox automatically

Comment: See the phonecat tutorial of angularjs (https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial). You will see all concept of angular